# Lorenz attractor with Runge-Kutta python

Tags: python, differential-equations, runge-kutta, lorenz-system

1. Hello I have to program a python function to solve Lorenz differential equations using Runge-Kutta 2cond grade

[image: Differential equation]

sigma=10, r=28 and b=8/3

with initial conditions (x,y,z)=(0,1,0)

this is the code i wrote, but it throws me an error saying overflow encountered in `double_scalars`, 
and I don't see what is wrong with the program

```
from pylab import *
def runge_4(r0,a,b,n,f1,f2,f3):
    def f(r,t):
        x=r[0]
        y=r[1]
        z=r[2]
        fx=f1(x,y,z,t)
        fy=f2(x,y,z,t)
        fz=f3(x,y,z,t)
        return array([fx,fy,fz],float)
    h=(b-a)/n
    lista_t=arange(a,b,h)
    print(lista_t)
    X,Y,Z=[],[],[]
    for t in lista_t:
        k1=h*f(r0,t)
        print("k1=",k1)
        k2=h*f(r0+0.5*k1,t+0.5*h)
        print("k2=",k2)
        k3=h*f(r0+0.5*k2,t+0.5*h)
        print("k3=",k3)
        k4=h*f(r0+k3,t+h)
        print("k4=",k4)
        r0+=(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/float(6)
        print(r0)
        X.append(r0[0])
        Y.append(r0[1])
        Z.append(r0[2])
    return array([X,Y,Z])

def f1(x,y,z,t):
    return 10*(y-x)
def f2(x,y,z,t):
    return 28*x-y-x*z
def f3(x,y,z,t):
    return x*y-(8.0/3.0)*z
#and I run it
r0=[1,1,1]

runge_4(r0,1,50,20,f1,f2,f3)
```

Comment: What about [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/lorenz_attractor.html)?

Comment: What is "Runge-Kutta 2nd grade"? Does that mean some RK2 method, midpoint or Heun? Then your code is wrong as you implemented the (better) RK4 method (all classical RK4 methods are due to M.W.Kutta).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solving differential equations numerically can be challenging. If you choose too high step sizes, the solution will accumulate high errors and can even become unstable, as in your case.

Either you should drastically reduce the step size (`h`) or just use the adaptive Runge Kutta method provided by `scipy`:

```
from numpy import array, linspace
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

def func(t, r):
    x, y, z = r 
    fx = 10 * (y - x)
    fy = 28 * x - y - x * z
    fz = x * y - (8.0 / 3.0) * z
    return array([fx, fy, fz], float)

# and I run it
r0 = [0, 1, 0]
sol = solve_ivp(func, [0, 50], r0, t_eval=linspace(0, 50, 5000))

# and plot it
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = pylab.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot3D(sol.y[0,:], sol.y[1,:], sol.y[2,:], 'blue')
pylab.show()
```

This solver uses 4th and 5th order Runge Kutta combination and controls the deviation between them by adapting the step size. See more usage documentation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You use a step size of `h=2.5`.

For RK4 the useful step sizes given a Lipschitz constant `L` are in the range `L*h=1e-3` to `0.1`, one might get somewhat right looking results up to `L*h=2.5`. Above that the method turns chaotic, any resemblance to the underlying ODE is lost.

The Lorenz system has a Lipschitz constant of about `L=50`, see [Chaos and continuous dependency of ODE solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3523873/115115), so `h<0.05` is absolutely required, `h=0.002` is better and `h=2e-5` gives the numerically best results for this numerical method.

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to a division by zero or when a limit of a type is exceeded (float type).

To figure out where and when it happens you can set `numpy.seterr('raise')` and it will raise an exception so you can debug and see what it's happening. It seems your algorithm is diverging.

Here you can se how to use [numpy.seterr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)